# SQL multiple tables into one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table of products and a separate table of images for any particular product.

`tblProducts`:

- productID
- productName

`tblProductImages`:

- productID
- imageFileName

I can return the product details and then the product images for that product with two separate queries but I'm unsure of how to get it into one query?

So for example I would like to see:

```
productID productName imageFilename imageFilename imageFilename
```

as my result set (will need to be dynamic because there could be anything from 1 to 10 images uploaded per product).

Is this something I can do with a PIVOT?

Thanks

Comment: do you really want to have dynamic number of columns in your result?

Comment: Cant you have 10 columns as fixed in your result and keep null value if imagefile is not there?

Comment: I strongly recommend either keeping the normalised set (with two queries) or a single set (as you want) but with a fixed number of fileName fields.

Comment: I agree with ~Dems, but I would do a join to do one query.

Comment: Marlin - Do you mean one table with products and then one with images but image1, image2, image3 as fields with the productID as reference?

That would then not be fully normalised I believe?

I think I may end up changing and implementing a maximum number of files to 10 which should be enough but I don't personally like that style of table layout.

It's probably best in this situation as although the answer below is great, it's a bit too much for what should be a simpler solution imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `PIVOT` for this result.  If you know the number of column then you can hard-code them:

```
select *
from
(
  select p.productid,
    p.productname,
    i.imagefilename,
    'ImageFile_' + 
      cast(row_number() over(partition by i.productid 
                order by i.productid) as varchar(10)) col
  from tblproducts p
  left join tblProductImages i
    on p.productid = i.productid
) x
pivot
(
  max(imagefilename)
  for col in ([ImageFile_1], [ImageFile_2], [ImageFile_3])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4aa72/8)

Or you can use dynamic SQL to generate the `PIVOT`. The dynamic will work in the event you have a changing number of `imagefilename`:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' 
                        + QUOTENAME('ImageFile_'+ cast(x.rn as varchar(10))) 
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by i.productid 
                          order by i.productid) rn
                      from tblProductImages i
                    ) x
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT productid, productname,' + @cols + ' 
              from 
             (
                select p.productid,
                  p.productname,
                  i.imagefilename,
                  ''ImageFile_'' + 
                    cast(row_number() over(partition by i.productid 
                              order by i.productid) as varchar(10)) col
                from tblproducts p
                left join tblProductImages i
                  on p.productid = i.productid
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(imagefilename)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4aa72/15)

Both results will be similar to this:

```
PRODUCTID | PRODUCTNAME |  IMAGEFILE_1 | IMAGEFILE_2 | IMAGEFILE_3
==================================================================
1         | Product 1   | Image1       | Image2      | Image3
2         | Product 2   | Image1       | Image2      | (null)
3         | Product 3   | Image1       | (null)      | (null)
4         | Product 4   | Image1       | Image2      | Image3
5         | Product 5   | Image1       | (null)      | (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

also Try like this.Just have a comma separeted filenames for each productID.

```
select p.productID,
(select STUFF((select ','+imageFileName from tblProductImages where productID=p.productID
for xml path('')),1,1,'')) as ImageFileNames
from tblProducts p
group by p.productID
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to give credit to @RomanParker.  However, I'm uncomfortable using an `apply` when the more common `join` is perfectly sufficient.  There are also a number of other changes to the query, notably aggregating *before* joining to the product table:

```
select P.productID, P.productName,
       imageFileName1,
       imageFileName2,
       imageFileName3,
       ...
       imageFileName10
from tblProducts as P left outer join
     (select I.productID,
             min(case when I.RowNum = 1 then I.imageFileName else null end) as imageFileName1,
             min(case when I.RowNum = 2 then I.imageFileName else null end) as imageFileName2,
             min(case when I.RowNum = 3 then I.imageFileName else null end) as imageFileName3,
             ...
             min(case when I.RowNum = 10 then I.imageFileName else null end) as imageFileName10
      from (select I.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by ProductId Order by (select NULL)) as RowNum
            from tblProductImages as I
           ) I
      group by I.productID
     )
     on p.productId = I.productID
```